# ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 7 and 1. Shapes are [7] and [1] in Tensorflow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a classification problem with 6 classes which I am trying to implement in Tensorflow with a BERT layer model.
Here are my data shapes.

```
# load data    
with open('.../News_Category_Dataset_v3.json','r') as f:
    jdata = f.read()

jdata2  = [json.loads(line) for line in jdata.split('\n') if line]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(jdata2)
label_dict = {'CRIME':0, 'BUSINESS':1, 'SPORTS':2 ,'WEDDINGS':3, 'DIVORCE':4, 'PARENTING':5}
        
df['label'] = df['category'].map(label_dict).fillna(6).astype(int)

X = df['short_description']
y = df['label']
......
print('Shape of training data: ',X_tf_train.shape)
print('Shape of test data: ',X_tf_test.shape)
Shape of training data:  (167621, 512) 
Shape of test data:  (41906, 512)
```

I also have this sample of my training data:

```
sample = X_tf_train[0:5]
print('Object type: ', type(dbert_tf(sample)))
print('Output format (shape): ',dbert_tf(sample)[0].shape)
print('Output used as input for the classifier (shape): ', dbert_tf(sample)[0][:,0,:].shape)


Object type:  <class 'transformers.modeling_tf_outputs.TFBaseModelOutput'>
Output format (shape):  (5, 512, 768)
Output used as input for the classifier (shape):  (5, 768)
```

My model is

```
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers, metrics

input_ids_in = layers.Input(shape=(512,), name='input_token', dtype='int32')

x = dbert_tf(input_ids=input_ids_in)[0][:,0,:]
x = layers.Dropout(0.2, name='dropout')(x)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense')(x)
x = layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax', name='classification')(x)

model_tf = models.Model(inputs=input_ids_in, outputs = x, name='ClassificationModelTF')

model_tf.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=[tfa.metrics.F1Score(average="macro",num_classes = 7,threshold=None,name='f1_score', dtype=None)])

model_tf.summary()
Model: "ClassificationModelTF"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_token (InputLayer)    [(None, 512)]             0         
                                                                 
 tf_distil_bert_model_1 (TFD  TFBaseModelOutput(last_h  66362880 
 istilBertModel)             idden_state=(None, 512,             
                             768),                               
                              hidden_states=None, att            
                             entions=None)                       
                                                                 
 tf.__operators__.getitem_6   (None, 768)              0         
 (SlicingOpLambda)                                               
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 768)               0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 64)                49216     
                                                                 
 classification (Dense)      (None, 7)                 455       
                                                                 
=================================================================
```

When I train the model, I get the following error:

```
history = model_tf.fit(X_tf_train, y_tf_train, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, epochs=20, validation_data=(X_tf_test, y_tf_test))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[24], line 1
----> 1 history = model_tf.fit(X_tf_train, y_tf_train, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, epochs=20, validation_data=(X_tf_test, y_tf_test))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file_o3avcss.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__train_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filezhsg__93.py:57, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
     55             raise
     56         return fscope_1.ret(retval__1, do_return_1)
---> 57 ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).true_positives.assign_add, (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(_weighted_sum), (ag__.ld(y_pred) * ag__.ld(y_true), ag__.ld(sample_weight)), None, fscope),), None, fscope)
     58 ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).false_positives.assign_add, (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(_weighted_sum), (ag__.ld(y_pred) * (1 - ag__.ld(y_true)), ag__.ld(sample_weight)), None, fscope),), None, fscope)
     59 ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).false_negatives.assign_add, (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(_weighted_sum), ((1 - ag__.ld(y_pred)) * ag__.ld(y_true), ag__.ld(sample_weight)), None, fscope),), None, fscope)

ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\ma\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\ma\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\metrics\f_scores.py", line 160, in update_state  *
        self.true_positives.assign_add(_weighted_sum(y_pred * y_true, sample_weight))

    ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 7 and 1. Shapes are [7] and [1]. for '{{node AssignAddVariableOp_2}} = AssignAddVariableOp[dtype=DT_FLOAT](AssignAddVariableOp_2/resource, Sum_2)' with input shapes: [], [7].
```

I have noticed that if I change this line

```
model_tf.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=[tfa.metrics.F1Score(average="macro",num_classes = 7,threshold=None,name='f1_score', dtype=None)])
```

with this one, for accuracy,

```
model_tf.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=[metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
```

Then it runs fine. so can the error  be specific to tensorlow-addons? I really wanted to use the F1-score metric.

Can someone advise me on this error please?

Comment: It seems it about your labels in training or validation, so would you give the shapes of these arrays beside the unique values inside them since you are using sparse category loss.